# Need review of Relational Algebra

Tags: relation-algebra

These are technically homework but I'd like to have verified whether what I did is right or wrong, so I don't upright ask for a solution at least.

• Find the names, street address, and cities of residence of all employees who work for “First Bank Corporation” and earn more than $10,000.

[image: First Answer]

• Find the IDs of all students who were taught by an instructor named Einstein; make sure there are no duplicates in the result.

The first solution assumes that you know what the ID for Physics lessons are since Einstein is the only person in this example who teaches Physics. Which is PHY-101.

[image: Second Answer First]

The next solution assumes you know nothing about this and need to find everything. The solution is pretty long and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

[image: Second Answer Second]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've tagged this with [*relation-algebra*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_algebra), but I don't see what Boolean algebras have to do with your question. Perhaps you meant the computer science topic [*relational algebra*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra)?

Comment: It's often used with Databases.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro There is no tag for relational algebra. We are [discussing](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12865/53208) it in meta.